# center absolute div in absolute div

Tags: html, css, angular, sass

I am trying to create a countdown that looks as follows:

[image: Countdown]

The countdown consits of 4 parts:

- a map as bottom (that dark part);
- a white container for the text (this is an svg);
- the actual time left;
- the text that describes the amount.

The problem I am facing is that the text is not shown on top of the white container. This is due to the fact that I am using a `::before` tag on the text and I cannot use `z-index: -1` on the `::before` because it would then go behind the map.

So I am forced to use 2 separate divs and align the text on top of the white container.

---

**Code**

The current code looks like this:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <span>{{countdown.days | slice:0:1}}</span>
  <span>{{countdown.days | slice:1:2}}</span>
  <span>{{countdown.days | slice:2:3}}</span>
  <p>{{"COUNTDOWN.DAYS" | translate}}</p>
</div>
```

Scss:

```
span {
  padding: 8px 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: $font-size-xl;
  color: $font-secondary-color;

  &:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 0.2em;
  }
}

span:not(.indicator)::before {
  content: "";
  background: url(../../../assets/img/counters/counterContainer.svg) no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
  width: 24px;
  height: 44px;
  margin-left: -5px;
  // z-index: -1;
  margin-top: -2px;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  color: $orange-light;
  font-weight: $font-weight-normal;
}
```

The code above results in the image of the countdown, but with the problem the the text is hidden behind the `span::before`.

---

**I have tried**

I have tried to use 2 absolute divs. This works for 1 number, but it doesn't align well next to eachother. Every following number is stacked on top of the last one. Also I cannot seem to center the text on top of the container.

HTML:

```
<div>
   <p>0</p> <!-- The time left -->
   <span></span> <!-- The white container -->
</div>
```

Scss:

```
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;

  p {
   position: absolute;
   display: inline-block;
   z-index: 2;
  }

  span {
   content: "",
   background: url(../../../assets/img/counters/counterContainer.svg) no-repeat;
   background-size: contain;
   position: absolute;
   width: 24px;
   height: 44px;
  }
}
```

---

So I do not know of any more or better options to align two divs on top of eachother and make other numbers align next to eachother (as shown).

---

**Update**

A simple code pen showing my problem: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EdpppV)

Comment: Please share a codepen or fiddle URL to help you out.

Comment: _“and I cannot use z-index: -1 on the ::before because it would then go behind the map”_ - even if you lift the span element itself onto a higher z-index first …?

Comment: @misorude, can you explain what you mean with that? Adding a parent div with a higher `z-index` would make the span element go behind the parent when using `z-index: -1`?

Comment: No, just give the span `position:relative; z-index:1;` …

Comment: @misorude, adding the code above to the span unfortunately doesn't solve it. See: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EdpppV. I think the problem lies with the fact that a `::before` can only be set behind the selected div with a `z-index: -1` or am I wrong on that one?

edit: 
Adding `z-index: 2` to the `span` and `z-index: 1` to the `span::before` doesn't solve it either

Comment: What’s not properly working, is your pen (SASS code, but editor set to normal CSS) … https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KGBJam is what you want to achieve, no?

Comment: @misorude You are right! I was to quick with pasting the code.. 
But your solution worked! could you make it an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> and I cannot use `z-index: -1` on the `::before` because it would then go behind the map

Easily fixable, if you “lift” the `span` element itself onto a higher `z-index` first:

```
span {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KGBJam

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using a flex box?

```css
.holder-thing {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: center;
  background: grey;
  height:100px;
  width:200px;
}

.white-box {
  width: 40px;
  height: 60px;
  background:white;
  
}

.number-thing {
  justify-content:center;
  display: flex;
  margin: 4px 4px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class='holder-thing'>
  <div class='number-thing'>
    <div class='white-box'></div>
    <div class='number-thing-text'>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='number-thing'>
    <div class='white-box'></div>
    <div class='number-thing-text'>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='number-thing'>
    <div class='white-box'></div>
    <div class='number-thing-text'>
      <p>text</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```